# Font not working issues with Firefox and Safari browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

Fonts that I have used:

- Avenir LT Std Book
- Avenir LT Std Roman
- Avenir LT Std Light

The CSS code I am using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir LT Std Roman';
    src: url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir LT Std Book';
    src: url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir LT Std Light';
    src: url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Light.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/AvenirLTStd-Light.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

### Chrome screenshot:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

### Firefox screenshot:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Comment: It does look like the font works, but FF has trouble with anti-aliasing or subpixel rendering. Do other fonts look ugly in FF too?

Comment: I try and change the other font still same issues I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

I’m wondering if this is a problem with the font’s [*hinting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting). Hints can be included within the font, that suggest to certain platforms how the glyph outlines should be rendered on the pixel grid.

Not all fonts, and not all versions of fonts, have hinting, and not all platforms use the hints. It would be helpful to know what version of Windows and Firefox you’re using, and what version of Avenir you’re using (ex. where did it come from?).

Typically, the OTF version of the file isn’t licensed for web use, so first of all you’ll probably want to remove it. If the WOFF and WOFF2 files were created from the OTF file, there might not have been any hints to begin with, and they probably wouldn’t be licensed for web use either.

I would:

- Compare the rendering on your site in the same browser, with the live web font preview on the [MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir/webfont_preview.html) site.
- If it’s better, consider licensing a web specific versions of Avenir or Avenir Next (the updated version of the typeface family) from [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/search/all-fonts?Licenses=Web&searchtext=avenir) or [MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir/webfont_preview.html) that has the better hinting. They should provide the WOFF and WOFF2

Alternatively, if it’s only happening for you locally on your copy of Windows + Firefox, these links might also be relevant:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1179694
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1233884

Hope that’s helpful!